# How to fit/clip an axis aligned bounding box around a portion of a triangle

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, clipping, aabb, triangle

I have looked and looked and cannot find any resources on. I want to clip an axis aligned bounding box against a triangle in a way that creates a new tight fitting axis aligned bounding box around or in the triangle (I have seen the reverse a lot, a triangle clipped against an axis alinged bounding, but never seen the reverse case). I tried computing the clipped tiangle then building a bounding box from it. But it is grossly inefficent and I don't think my code is correct. Does anyone know how to clip a bounding box against a triangle efficently?

Here is pictures describing what I currently do

[image]
[image]
[image]

```cpp
typedef uint8_t  u8;
typedef uint16_t u16;
typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef uint64_t u64;
typedef int8_t   s8;
typedef int16_t  s16;
typedef int32_t  s32;
typedef int64_t  s64;
typedef float    f32;
typedef double   f64;

struct Point
{
    union
    {
        f32 a[3];
        struct
        {
            f32 x;
            f32 y;
            f32 z;
        };
    };
};

struct BoundingBox3
{
    Point m_vMin = {FLT_MAX,FLT_MAX,FLT_MAX};
    Point m_vMax = {-FLT_MAX,-FLT_MAX,-FLT_MAX};
};

inline
s8 Classify( s8 sign, u8 axis, const Point *c_v, const Point *p_v )
{
    const f64 d = sign * ( p_v->a[axis] - c_v->a[axis] );
    if ( d > EPSILON )
    {
        return  1;
    }
    else if ( d < -EPSILON )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return  0;
}

#define POINT_BUFFER_SIZE 9

inline
void Clip3D_plane( Point *pVerts, s8 sign, u8 axis, u8 *pdwNumVerts, const Point *pPointOnPlane )
{
    u8 dwNumVerts = ( *pdwNumVerts );
    if ( dwNumVerts == 0 )
    {
        return;
    }
    else if ( dwNumVerts == 1 )
    {
        *pdwNumVerts = 0;
        return;
    }

    Point vNewVerts[POINT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    u8 k = 0;
    bool b = true; // polygon is fully located on clipping plane

    Point v1 = pVerts[dwNumVerts - 1];
    s8 d1 = Classify( sign, axis, pPointOnPlane, &v1 );
    for ( u8 j = 0; j < dwNumVerts; ++j )
    {
        const Point &v2 = pVerts[j];
        s8 d2 = Classify( sign, axis, pPointOnPlane, &v2 );

        if ( d2 != 0 )
        {
            b = false;
            if ( ( 0x80 & ( d2 ^ d1 ) ) != 0 ) //if signs differ
            {
                const f32 fAlpha = ( v2.a[axis] - pPointOnPlane->a[axis] ) / ( v2.a[axis] - v1.a[axis] );
                Point_Lerp( &v2, &v1, fAlpha, &vNewVerts[k++] );
            }
            else if ( d1 == 0 && ( k == 0 || !Point_Equals( &vNewVerts[k - 1], &v1 ) ) )
            {
                vNewVerts[k++] = v1;
            }

            if ( d2 > 0 )
            {
                vNewVerts[k++] = v2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( d1 != 0 )
            {
                vNewVerts[k++] = v2;
            }
        }

        v1 = v2;
        d1 = d2;
    }

    if ( b )
    {
        return;
    }

    *pdwNumVerts = k;
    for ( u8 j = 0; j < k; ++j )
    {
        pVerts[j] = vNewVerts[j];
    }
}

inline void BoundingBox_Append( BoundingBox3 *pBB, const Point *pvPoint )
{
    pBB->m_vMin.x = min( pBB->m_vMin.x, pvPoint->x );
    pBB->m_vMin.y = min( pBB->m_vMin.y, pvPoint->y );
    pBB->m_vMin.z = min( pBB->m_vMin.z, pvPoint->z );
    pBB->m_vMax.x = max( pBB->m_vMax.x, pvPoint->x );
    pBB->m_vMax.y = max( pBB->m_vMax.y, pvPoint->y );
    pBB->m_vMax.z = max( pBB->m_vMax.z, pvPoint->z );
}

void BoundingBox_ClipAndAppendTri( BoundingBox3 *pBB3, Point *pVerts, u8 *phwNumVerts, const BoundingBox3 *pClipBox )
{
    for ( u8 axis = 0; axis < 3; ++axis )
    {
        Clip3D_plane( pVerts, 1, axis, phwNumVerts, &pClipBox->m_vMin );
        Clip3D_plane( pVerts, -1, axis, phwNumVerts, &pClipBox->m_vMax );
    }
    for ( u8 vert = 0; vert < *phwNumVerts; ++vert )
    {
        BoundingBox_Append( pBB3, &pVerts[vert] );
    }
}
```

Comment: @AustinWBryan i'm asking about geometry not so much the code... stackoverflow at it's finest

Comment: In computational geometry problems, in many cases, all point information is provided in the form of integer. If you carefully consider all cases in detail, it will probably be. It is very important to carefully consider all possible cases for CG problems.

Comment: @yosmo78 I'm aware. I'm just baffled by this decision, and the better formatted your code is, the happier your teammates, coworkers, and strangers on SO will be when reading it

Comment: @AustinWBryan it's the code standard at my work... we all use those typedefs (3 char per type name plus a well defined bit width (we change the definition of f32 and f64 per platform if those are not the bit widths))

Comment: @yosmo78 In that case, my apologizes. I would seriously hate to work in a system like that, I feel like that overcomplicates things a lot

Comment: `but never the reverse case`  - but...is there any difference in result?

Comment: @MBo the result would be an axis aligned bounding box, so yes. (the reverse case gives you an n-gon) I will edit my question

Comment: But intersection points are the same in both cases, you just have to get min/max for every coordinate of these points to make bounding box

Comment: @MBo right, i worded my response wrong. My issue is that that method is really slow, is there a faster way to do so?

Comment: @real_fan: let me disagree. In Computational Geometry, coordinates are usually reals (elements of $\mathbb R$), which model continuous space.

Comment: @Yves Daoust In case of managing coordinates with float, there are many cases where accurate judgment cannot be made because of floating point error. When examining the coordinates as real numbers as an example, we can determine that (10^18+1, 10^18), (0, 0), and (10^18, 10^18-1) are on a straight line. However, if we use the integer type, we can use the int256 type to make an accurate decision.

Comment: @real_fan: Computational Geometry does not deal with floats but with real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can't escape computing intersection points between the sides of the triangle and those of the box. To get a correct result, you need to compute the intersection of the two shapes, for instance using the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm, that you can specialize for the case of a triangle and a rectangle. If I am right, in the worst case you get an heptagon.

Then getting the AABB is no big deal.

---

Alternatively, you can implement a line-segment clipping algorithm against a poygonal (triangular or rectangular) window. A specialization to an AA window is the Cohen-Sutherland algorithm. Then clip all triangle sides against the rectangle and all rectangle sides against the triangle.